# Pipe directly to a Tmux pane

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

I've been looking at the available Tmux commands and I can see, out of the box, that I can pipe output from a pane elsewhere or write to the terminal assigned to the session.

I would like to have background processes `A`, `B` and `C` all piping their output to a particular pane in a particular session. How could this be arranged?

Answer (score 2):

This approach will work if processes were in panes ie. you see there output inside panes not in background

First you have to know the particular pane pts , use this command :

```
ps ax | grep $$ | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

The output will be like `pts/5`

Then we redirect the output of desired precesses pane to this pts `5`

```
tmux pipe-pane -o -t 0.2 'cat > /dev/pts/5'; \
tmux pipe-pane -o -t 0.3 'cat > /dev/pts/5'; \
tmux pipe-pane -o -t 0.4 'cat > /dev/pts/5';
```

`-o` for open new pipe , `-t` for target-pane